# Google reCAPTCHA undefined index g-recaptcha-response in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

I just want to ask why my reCAPTCHA is not working when my form is in the bootstrap's modal? Have you ever experienced it?

**sign.php**

```
if(empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) === false){
    echo "Set.";
} else {
    echo "Not set.";
}
```

**index.php**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open form
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="sign.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                Name:
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                reCaptcha:
                <div id="r1" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc-xQUUAAAAAFc4apq1qbS_VI-ZTJHalsj5BGaa"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

..I have `sign.php` to check if the reCAPTCHA is working. Although it is working if I dont use modal, but when I used modal, the recaptcha validation(sign.php) is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are not submitting the value of the recaptcha to the backend i.e to php script. Your submit button should be inside `</form>` tag else your form will not get submitted.

**check**

your response to the backend---

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
  $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  echo($response);
 }
 else {
 echo"value is not passing to the php script";
   }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for that, I just did not include the submit button. anyways, I have also tried it (your php script code), but still doesn't work.

Comment: It is working if I dont use the modal of bootstrap, but if I try the modal, my validation not works. And if I dont use `If else` in php code, just `echo $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']`, it gets an error, says "undefined index: g-recaptcha-response".

Comment: can you try the updated code in the answer..see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="showModal" type="button">Show Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="captcha"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#showModal").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    setTimeout(function() {
        createRecaptcha();
    }, 100);
});



function createRecaptcha() {
    grecaptcha.render("captcha", {sitekey: "6LcgSAMTAAAAACc2C7rc6HB9ZmEX4SyB0bbAJvTG", theme: "light"});
}
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/emilhem/Lgovn28f/4/

Comment: My reCAPTCHA also appears but, when I try to validate it using my PHP code above, it's really not working.